# Use just date instead of datetime in Flutter, Firestore & Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a Flutter app with Cloud functions.

I understand from all the questions raised and answered here that Firestore stores DateTime. And in Cloud functions when I use Timestamp.toDate(), the value returned is in the server timezone which happens to be UTC.

The challenge I'm facing is:

Date sent to Firestore: **31 Jan 2021** from the app in IST timezone

It gets stored in Firestore as a timestamp: **30 Jan 2021 18:30:00UTC** because the app actually sends 31 Jan 2021 00:00:00+5:30 which gets converted to UTC.

When I open the app in India, the date shows up correctly as 31 Jan 2021.
But when someone opens the app in (say) New York, the app shows the value as 30 Jan 2021 (I'm omitting the time in the display).

I understand why this is happening and probably a best practice for me is to convert the date in Flutter to 31Jan2021 00:00:00 UTC (instead of 00:00:00+5:30) before sending it to Firestore and then whenever displaying the value back to again ensure the date is shown in UTC instead of the local timezone.

**My question is** whether there is a package or means to globally enforce the dates in UTC in Flutter.  The other option would be to do the conversion every time I read or write a DateTime value with Firestore!

Or maybe what is the best way to store a date in Firestore? I read in another post as someone storing it as a String instead of a Timestamp.  Maybe that is the right way or maybe store as Number.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `String` datatype if you want to store only date in the Firestore, to avoid the kind of confusion that you are encountering.

For detailed information, you can refer to this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615487/15774177).